# cannot create clean url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I provided this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lebmotors.com/new/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.lebmotors.com/new/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ moreprod.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3
```

Still it does not work
I get: `http://www.lebmotors.com/new/moreprod.php?id=107&topid=4&catid=8`
What AM I doing wrong
Many Thanks

Comment: you only need a single `RewriteEngine On` at the top

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess ? Root folder or `new` folder ? Also, what are you trying to do with first rule (`HTTP_HOST`) ? Because it's wrong. For the rest, i'll post a solution but i'm waiting for your precision

Comment: I am doing it on folder new/
 Also, what are you trying to do with first rule (HTTP_HOST) ?
Just follewed steps by an online tutorial and placed it
Removed additional rewrite engine declarations, that was my mistake of copy paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to repeat `RewriteEngine On` directive.

Then, when you add your rules, you still can access your pages via `moreprod.php` (but you can also access it from new clean url).

Here's how your htaccess should look like, assuming `moreprod.php` is also in `new` folder

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /morenews\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . morenews/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^morenews/([^/]+)/$ morenews.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3 [L]
```

With this code, if you try (for example) to reach `http://domain.com/new/moreprod.php?id=123&topid=456&catid=789` then you'll redirect to `http://domain.com/new/moreprod/123/456/789/`

**Conclusion**
You can now access your pages via clean urls like

- `http://domain.com/new/moreprod/123/` (id=123)
- `http://domain.com/new/moreprod/123/456/` (id=123 and topid=456)
- `http://domain.com/new/moreprod/123/456/789/` (id=123 and topid=456 and catid=789)

Comment: Ok This DID work but reached http://www.lebmotors.com/new/107/4/8/ and css got ruined ??? and clicking more links gor me to: http://www.lebmotors.com/new/107/4/8/banks.php no such page

Comment: That's because you're using **relative** paths instead of **absolute** paths in your html links (js, css, imgs, href links). You have 2 possibilities. First is to add `/new/` in the beginning of each links. Second option is to add `<base href="/new/">` right after `<head>` html tag in all your concerned pages

Comment: Thanks a billion, it is working,I did the same process for more enws and it worked
what If I want to keep a title for search engines like:
http://www.lebmotors.com/new/12/ To take http://www.lebmotors.com/new/news/12/ and the same /prod/

Comment: Placing a fourth is breaking the page, this line in particular
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]
I placed then had to remove to
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)&cagid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
....
It reaches:
http://www.lebmotors.com/new/114/5/6/1/ and breaks, removing the last 1/ works

Comment: This is my updated version, I have commented the line that causes the break: page not found and ones related to it:

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /morenews\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/? [R=301,L]

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)&cagid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/%4/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ morenews?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3 [L]

Comment: #RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3&cagid=$4 [L]

Comment: When you want 4 parameters, you have to use this: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)&cagid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC] 
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/%4/? [R=301,L]` and add this rule after `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3&cagid=$4 [L]`. Also, this rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1 [L]` won't never ever be matched since previous one `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ morenews?id=$1 [L]` is matching the same but forwards to another file (you have to use a prefix in url to distinct both of them)

Comment: Thank you very much, I want to keep some pagename before it, like the others, I removed .php, this worked, want to place something like /product/1/2/3/4/ Many Thanks I appreciate your help

Comment: I am placing action = 'page' without php so the paramters reach them, is there a workaround, instead of having to rename every action ='somepage.php' to action = 'somepage'

Comment: How can I reverse this operation in the back office

Comment: You should update your question with what you want **exactly**. It´s hard to do it in here

Comment: Hello, I want to reverse the operation in the back office so .php is reserved, and want to make it like www.lebmotors.com/new/product/1/2/3/4 instead of www.lebmotors.com/new/1/2/3/4 thanks a lot

Comment: Ok but i still don't get what you mean by `so .php is reserved`. You want to access your files with or without extension ?

Comment: Hello, i the front office public yes, I removed .php, this is working, but in the back office I want to return to dafault, the public is on website/new/ the admin is on website/new/administrationfolder there I want to return to the default, this is because every form where I removed the .php, I had to change it to action=somepage1 where it was action = somepage1.php,

Comment: I resolved it my placing rewrite engine = off in the administration, I just want to keep moreprod after new/ so that it takes me to website/new/moreprod/2/3/4 ....

Comment: You can see my edited answer for `moreprod` prefix in url. If it's ok then you can mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful

Comment: Hello, I ahve tried this approach a while ago with other approaches, and used this one, I tried it on the news and it gives me internal script error
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /morenews\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . morenews/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^morenews/([^/]+)/$ morenews?id=$1 [L]
It takes me here with internal server error
http://www.lebmotors.com/new/morenews/12/

Comment: I added an example in my edited answer. Please stop posting comments again and again to keep asking something else each time. You now have more than what you asked in your initial question. If you have something else to ask, please post another question. Otherwise, mark my answer as accepted to close your question

Comment: Ok I will mark this and ask a new question, I am searching for the option, Thanks a lot, I am new here and do not all these options to amrk and ask a new or comment here, excuse me for this, All I wenated to say is I have tried this approach and it gave me this error

Comment: No problem. If you try with my code only you should not have any error and should be working as expected (like it was working before)

Comment: This is the approach amd leads to 500 internals erver, anyway I have moved it to another question, sorry again I am quite anaware of the rules and best approaches Ia m fresh here
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /morenews\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . morenews/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC] Error 500

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, just moved these lines to the bottom of .htaccess

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /new/
        ....
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
        RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/? [R=301,L]
        .....
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)&cagid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
        RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/%2/%3/%4/? [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1 [L]
        .....
        RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3&cagid=$4 [L]
        # THIS TO THE BOTTOM
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```